# How do I test whether a path is absolute in Elisp?

Tags: path, elisp, absolute-path

I'm doing some path manipulation in Emacs Lisp, and I want to know how to test whether a string represents an absolute path. What is the canonical way to do this? Note that I don't want to check whether the path actually exists on the file system, I just want to check if a string represents an absolute path or not.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just found the answer: `file-name-absolute-p`.